# Adding static methods to facilitate cleaner unit tests - good practice?

Tags: java, unit-testing, scala

Say I have this class:

```
class MyClass {
    private String s;
    // more attributes here
    public MyClass(String s, /*more constructor params*/)  {...}

    public String myMethod(String s) {
        //complex logic here
    }
}
```

To unit test `myMethod()` I need to create the entire object (with many parameters that need constructed, etc), while the method only uses s.

Altenatelly I can add a static method:

```
class MyClass {
    private String s;
    // more attributes here
    public MyClass(String s, /*more constructor params*/)  {...}

    public String myMethod(String s) {
        return myStaticMethod(s);
    }

    public static myStaticMethod(String s) {
        //complex logic here
    }
}
```

Now I can easily test "complex logic" without the need to create the object. 
`someStaticMethod(String s)` should have no side-effects on the class.
So I am adding an extra method just for the ease of testing.
Is this a good practice?

Comment: A lot of good answers here, with focus on OO and TDD. Coming from the Scala community, with it's emphasis on functional programming (beside OO) I expected more support for the ease of testing of static methods (if they are pure functions, i.e. not affecting the state of the object). Also note that the static method does not need to be public.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, you've made a complex method a member of an object even though it has <strike>nothing</strike> little to do with that instance?

Yes, I agree you should use a different design. It *could* be a static method in that class, or factored into its own class. *Or* it might be a method of an object that implements a "Strategy" pattern. The right decision depends on the potential for change.

---

Maybe something like this:

```
class ComplexLogician {

  String myMethod(String a, String b) {
    /* Complex logic here. */
  }

}

class MyClass {

  private String s;

  private final ComplexLogician logic;

  /* More attributes here... */

  MyClass(String s, ComplexLogician logic, /* More parameters... */)  {...}

  String myMethod(String b) {
    return logic.myMethod(s, b);
  }

}
```

Comment: The method cannot be static since it uses (only) one field of the class. it's "almost" static, therefore the idea of creating a static method for testing.

Comment: @Adrian In your example, you show the string `s` being passed as a parameter to `myMethod()`. Is that not accurate? Or does it use a field of the object *and* a parameter?

Answer (score 3):

I think it would be better to not make the method static, but construct your object once in a "Before" method which will run before each test in the test class. Something like this

```
public class SampleTestSuite  {
    private MyClass myClass;

    @Before
    public void startUp(){
    myClass = new MyClass();//Will be called before each test method is called.

    }

    @Test
    public void testNavigationSucceeded() {
        assert...
    }

    @Test
    public void secondTest() {
        assert...
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the method can be static then it should be static regardless you need it for testing or whatever. You can switch on warnings in Eclipse for that. Eclipse gives you a warning then about non-static methods that can be static.

Comment: It can't be static, since it uses a field (s). But it can be made to call a static method.

Comment: When you can separate the complex logic into a static method then do it regardless you need it for testing. It makes things more clear. Also consider things @erickson said. It MAY even be reasonable to place the method somewhere else - a utility class, ... But you've to keep in mind that your test is only testing the "static part", so it is not really a alternative for testing your instance method.

Answer (score 2):

Changing your production code and expose its "guts" so that you can test it is a very bad practice. It breaks encapsulation, and if your code is not testable in the first place, that usually means it needs refactoring.

The "complex logic" that you wanted to move in a static method would certainly benefit a proper OO treatment. **Make a specialist class to handle that logic**, or a set of classes, inject them into your `MyClass` through interface, separate concerns, and your testing will be made a lot easier.

Better even, start with your tests (TDD) using a mocking framework, and that will drive a good design organically without the need for static methods or similar hacks.

**Example:** Let's say your `MyClass` needs to heavily transform one of its parameters (in your case, the `String s` before it can be used. So you wanted to extract that treatment into a static method? Instead of that, add to your class a dependency to, say, a `StringTransformer` (rename accordingly) that is an interface to the actual implementation you want. Have a method `transform(String s)` in the transformer, that would contain the logic you wanted. Then test your implementation using normal ways, job done. And you actually made your design better.

Comment: Made you design better, or added complication that wasn't required? I'm a long time advocate of TDD, but introducing classes into a system that don't represent real points of inflection should not be done lightly.

Comment: I disagree (but I know there is a debate), I constantly fight to keep my classes small and readable, and that means extracting to a new class as soon as I can bundle some functionalities together. To me, that reduces complexity :) And makes testing a lot easier

Answer (score 1):

I often write parts of the functionality of a class as package protected static methods, passing in field values as required. It lets you test functionality comprehensively without splitting it out into a separate class. It can give comprehensive test coverage without adding too much complication.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is not good practice to expose any functionality more than what is expected from the class. This would hinder from moving away from that logic easily since other clients might have started to use the code given that the method is public. One other option is to make the function protected so that in the same package within the test hierarchy, the test cases could be written. However, I would choose to write the test case by forming a base object once and keep changing my inputs and output set in it than using these work-arounds.

Answer (score 0):

If you only test your static method then you leave your instance method uncovered.  You could instead alter the instance method so that it can be tested.  If you post more details of a particular case here or as a new question I'm sure someone will help you to make it testable.